# How to get already set wireless access point details

Tags: android

since we can set wireless access point in android device from device settings,
then through android application i want to retrieve already set access point information like name,ip address,port number etc.Any idea/sample code/links how to do this?

Comment: Did you look through the APIs in [android.net.wifi](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/package-summary.html)?

Comment: yes I've gone through APIs,but not able to find how to get already set access point (in android device) details.Please help

Comment: I have also tried : List<WifiConfiguration> results= wifi.getConfiguredNetworks();int sizeConfigured=result.size(); But getting nullpointer exception